# Is there anyway can create a "new" global variable each time I call a function in C source file?

Tags: c, global-variables

Test is on 32-bit Linux x86, I use `gcc 4.6.3`.

I have two C source files, which are `main.c` and `foo.c`. They look like this (I simplified this problem):

**main.c**

```
extern void foo(void);

void main()
{
    foo();
    foo();
}
```

**foo.c**

```
static int g = 0;
int g1 = 0;

void foo()
{
  printf("%d\n", g);
  g = 123;
  printf("%d\n", g);

  printf("%d\n", g1);
  g1 = 123;
  printf("%d\n", g1);
}
```

The result is :

```
0
123
0
123
123
123
123
123
```

So my question is:

Is there any way that, each time I call function in `foo.c`, a **new global variables** will be initialized? and the correct output would be:

```
0
123
0
123
0
123
0
123
```

I am not familiar with C, however, I am asked to make a source code translation tool towards C code, someone designed how to implement that tool somehow, leaving this weird problem to me.

Could anyone give me some help?

Comment: Make it a local variable instead?

Comment: I agree with Mehrdad. If you don't want it to hold its value across calls, in what sense would it be global?

Comment: @Mehrdad, it seems impossible.. Cause actually in the `foo.c` file, there are large number of functions, relying on these global varibles...

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I am not joking, really **large number of functions** :)

Comment: @computereasy: Well if the code is already doing it the wrong way then you're going to have a bad time...

Comment: `main` returns `int`, not `void`, and a function with no parameters is declared and defined with `(void)`, not `int`.

Comment: @computereasy What is the real problem you are trying to solve? Creating new global variable is not possible in the language and you probably know that.

Comment: this is likely the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/230282)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reinitialize the variables at the start of `foo`:

```
void foo()
{
  g = 0;
  g1 = 0;

  printf("%d\n", g);
  g = 123;
  printf("%d\n", g);

  printf("%d\n", g1);
  g1 = 123;
  printf("%d\n", g1);
}
```

This way, `g` and `g1` are set to 0 each time `foo` is called (and then `foo` sets them to other values).

Comment: Hi! I just can not use local variables, because basically in the `foo.c` file, there are lots of functions, all of which relying on these global variables...

Comment: @computereasy: The variables are still global here.  If you mean that you'd have to add `g=0; g1=0;` to every single function in foo.c, well, better get to typing.

Comment: @computereasy: The problem is you're already doing it the wrong way. Two wrongs don't make a right. Fix the "lots of functions" instead of looking for a nonexistent solution.

Answer (score -1):

Reinitialize it between function calls

```
void main()
{
    foo();
    g = 0;
    g1 = 0;
    foo();
}
```

Note that it should be `int main(void)`